# Obtener el valor mas reciente de multiples grupos

Tags: mysql

Estoy intentando obtener los registros insertados mas recientes, pero agrupados por `warehouse_id`, todo sobre la misma tabla.

```sql
id       product_id  warehouse_id  transaction_date      quantity_in   quantity_out  stock 
2084      9836       1             2019-11-21 19:32:40   4             NULL          4
12001     9836       5             2019-11-28 23:15:02   5             NULL          5
12002     9836       1             2019-11-29 23:51:13   5             NULL          9
12003     9836       1             2019-11-30 00:01:20   1             NULL          10
```

El resultado que deseamos es:

```sql
id    product_id  warehouse_id  stock
12003 9836        1             10
12001 9836        5             5
```

hasta ahora hemos implementado:

```sql
SELECT 
    product_in.id AS id,
    product_in.product_id AS product_id,
    product_in.warehouse_id AS warehouse_id,
    product_in.stock AS stock
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            MAX(lpp.id) AS id
        FROM product_costs_log_pp lpp
        WHERE lpp.quantity_in > 0
        GROUP BY lpp.warehouse_id , lpp.product_id
    ) lpp
JOIN product_costs_log_pp product_in ON product_in.id = lpp.id
WHERE product_id = 9836
```

Pero esta consulta es sumamente ineficiente, y dependiendo de las entradas que halla registrado cada producto puede demorar hasta mas de 1 minuto, tiempo en el cual nuestro servidor rechaza la conexión. ¿existe otra manera para realizar esto de manera eficiente?

He investigado que existe una forma de hacer esto evitando los subquerys haciendo join de forma recursiva pero solo aplica si los registros solo estuvieran definidos por fecha y en nuestro caso necesitamos tambien distinguirlos por `warehouse_id`, Además sé de la exitencia de una funcionalidad nativa para esto en mysql 8 pero nosotros usamos una versión inferior (5.7.26)

Answer (score -1):

ya probaste con un `order by`? puedes intentar hacer la query de la siguiente manera.

```
SELECT 
    product_in.id AS id,
    product_in.product_id AS product_id,
    product_in.warehouse_id AS warehouse_id,
    product_in.stock AS stock
FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            MAX(lpp.id) AS id
        FROM product_costs_log_pp lpp
        WHERE lpp.quantity_in > 0
        GROUP BY lpp.warehouse_id , lpp.product_id
    ) lpp
JOIN product_costs_log_pp product_in ON product_in.id = lpp.id
WHERE product_id = 9836 order by transaction_date
```

también puedes guiarte [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11493463/mysql-order-timestamp-values-ascending-in-order-from-newest-to-oldest) que tuvo una duda parecida a la tuya

Comment: ¿En qué ayudará añadir `ORDER BY`?, el problema radica en en subquery anidado debido a que consulta la totalidad de los registros antes de devolver el conjunto de registros deseados, además dicha consulta se multiplica si deseo consultar mas de un producto.

Comment: había entendido mal tu pregunta, pensé que te referías a ordernarlos por fecha. pero también podrías intentar hacer una vista de la subconsulta, y cada que desees buscar los valores lo haces por medio de esa vista